# How can I manage a child_process from separate node.js processes?

Tags: node.js

I want to spawn a child process from a node.js process and after performing certain async operations, I want to pause the process.

Then another Node.js process will be running which needs to resume the process based on some event it will be listening to.

I can't seem to find how can I accomplish this in node.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Redis Pub/Sub to achieve this.

Refer: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/multi-instance-nodejs-app-in-paas-using-redis-pubsub--cms-22239

Comment: Thanks Vineet. While you have pointed in the direction of establishing communication between two separate node.js processes, my problem is a little more difficult to tackle. I need them to control a common unix child_process and need help in that direction.

Comment: This should help you achieve event based control across processes, if you can be a bit more specific I can try to help you on it :)

Comment: This helped indeed! My approach towards the solution needed to change. Event based solution worked great. thanks!